# Why doesn't "correct" change to False in this if-else ladder of conditions for date-checking?

Tags: python

I have `correct = bool()` declared outside any function or loop in the beginning of the script. I define a function and have the following conditions. Here is my code.

```
correct = bool()
```

...

```py
def part1():
    global date, now, m, d, query


    #getting the date
    raw = input("Date: (MM/DD) ")
    #splitting the date by /
    m, d = raw.split("/")
    #checking for invalid date


    if int(m) > 12 or int(m) < 1:
        print("Something's wrong with your date.1")
        correct = False
    #February 29
    if int(m) == 2 and int(d) > 29:
        print("Something's wrong with your date.2")
        correct = False
    if int(m) in thirties and int(d) > 30:
        print("Something's wrong with your date.3")
        correct = False
    if int(m) in thirty_ones and int(d) > 31:
        print("Something's wrong with your date.4")
        correct = False
    if int(d) < 1:
        print("Something's wrong with your date.5")
        correct = False
    else:
        correct = True

    print(correct)
    #creating string of date from numbers
    if correct == True:
        date = months[m] + " " + d
        print("Date = ", date)
        #creating query
        query = months[m] + " " + d
        print("Query: " + query)
```

If I input 01/35 (January 35, obviously an invalid date), it goes through the conditions and prints "Something's wrong with your date.4", telling me it's faulty by the condition `if int(m) in thirty_ones and int(d) > 31:` (`thirty_ones` is a list of numbers representing months which have 31 days declared along with `correct = bool()`). Since it printed that statement, then it would've made `correct = False`. However, the query is generated, even if `correct = False`. Why is that?

(apologies for the indentation problems in the code)

Comment: When you have more than one `if` predicate, you should use `elif`.

Comment: I think it is simpler to try to convert it to `datetime.date`, and if it succeeds you know it is a valid date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `elif`.

```
if int(m) > 12 or int(m) < 1:
    print("Something's wrong with your date.1")
    correct = False
    #February 29
elif int(m) == 2 and int(d) > 29:
    print("Something's wrong with your date.2")
    correct = False
elif int(m) in thirties and int(d) > 30:
    print("Something's wrong with your date.3")
    correct = False
elif int(m) in thirty_ones and int(d) > 31:
    print("Something's wrong with your date.4")
    correct = False
elif int(d) < 1:
    print("Something's wrong with your date.5")
    correct = False
else:
    correct = True
```

Comment: You could just initialize `correct` to `False` once at the top , then remove all of the other `False` assignments.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the following condition.

```html
if int(d) < 1:
    print("Something's wrong with your date.5")
    correct = False
else:
    correct = True
```

This code is getting executed after "if int(m) in thirty_ones and int(d) > 31" condition and it goes to else and set it to True.

Answer (score 1):

You apparently didn't declare `global correct`, so the toplevel assignment `correct = bool()` gets masked by the assignment inside the function. Anyway, don't use globals, it's terrible practice.

Also, your code is quite convoluted, you can make the if-elif ladder shorter and clearer with the following.

- Python allows triple conditions with <, <=, so instead of `int(m) > 12 or int(m) < 1`, do `not 1 <= m <= 12`. Python gets that right and doesn't even need parens around the `not ...`
- all your your `if...elif` ladder's early-terminations give False, so just set that at the top, and override it if you get to the successful clause. Or else move `check_date(m, d)` into a separate predicate helper function, and call it.

Code like this:

```
m, d = [int(_) for _ in raw.split("/")]

# checking for invalid date
if not 1 <= m <= 12:
    return False
elif m == 2 and d > 29:
    print("Something's wrong with your date.2")
    return False
elif m > 30 and d > 30:
    print("Something's wrong with your date.3")
    return = False
elif m = 31 and d > 31:
    print("Something's wrong with your date.4")
    return False
else:
    return True
```

Notes:

- Python allows triple conditions with <, <=, >, >=, ==
- you only ever use the `int()` values of m and d, so convert them at the top, already. Doing that in a list comprehension saves an extra line.